# How can I register a DLL which I created in C++

Tags: visual-c++, com, visual-studio-2005

I created a DLL in C++ using Visual Studio 2005. My problem is that I cannot register this DLL. Show me the error: "LoadLibrary(MyDll.dll) failed. The specified module could not be found."

Someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library depends on another library and that other library is missing.

To resolve this either use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find which library it depends on or [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see exactly which library loading fails.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)
2. Open your dll with it.
3. See which are the missing modules.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But my problem is persisting, now show me the error: "LoadLibrary(MyDll.dll) failed. This application has failed to start because the appication configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem".
I think that the problem is not the DLL, because I managed to register it on my computer. When I try to log into another computer gives the error

Comment: my guess is that there is something is missing in the PATH environment variable . Because of that, one of the dll to which your dll links fails to load (as the system is unable to find it). What happened when you tried opening it with dependency walker?

Comment: Sorry. I make mistake, the problem is not solved. I solved all the problems of dependence and have checked the environment variables, but the error above is persisting.
Do you have another ideia?

Thanks